# How can I use this Java function in Scala in a UDF?

Tags: java, scala, class, constructor, user-defined-functions

I have created a UDF in Scala (that im using with Spark btw) in order to get as a parameter a string and output a BeiderMorseEncoder string. I am using the
org.apache.commons.codec.language.bm.BeiderMorseEncoder Java function from Apache Commons

```
import org.apache.commons.codec.language.bm.BeiderMorseEncoder
class BeiderMorseEncode extends UDF1[String, String] {
  override def call(input: String): String = {
    val m = new BeiderMorseEncoder()
    m.encode(input)
  }
}

object BeiderMorseEncode {
  def apply(): BeiderMorseEncode = {
    new BeiderMorseEncode()
  }
}
```

It works great!
However I want to also use the following function (click to see signature) [org.apache.commons.codec.language.bm.Lang.guessLanguage](https://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-codec/apidocs/org/apache/commons/codec/language/bm/Lang.html#guessLanguage-java.lang.String-)

if I try to create a similar UDF for this function in Scala like this :

```
import org.apache.commons.codec.language.bm.Lang
class guessNameLanguage extends UDF1[String, String] {
  override def call(input: String): String = {


    val m = new Lang()
    m.guessLanguage(input)
  }
}

object guessNameLanguage {
  def apply(): guessNameLanguage = {
    new guessNameLanguage()
  }
}
```

I am getting

> org.apache.commons.codec.language.bm.Lang does not have a constructor

Any ideas on how can I make this work? I undersntand that I need to instantiate an object that has a constructor first ... but having had a look on the class hierarchy I dont see what object that would be. (it is obviously not Lang)

Apologies for my cringy Scala.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you look closely at the **Javadoc** you will see that the class provides two `static` methods to get instances of it.

So your code should end up being like this:

```scala
import org.apache.commons.codec.language.bm.{Lang, NameType}

val m = Lang.instance(NameType.GENERIC)
m.guessLanguage(input)
```

Comment: Many thanks this did the trick. Also this will help me a bit more understanding how to access similar functions